# MouseMove Not Recognizing Position

Tags: vb.net, mousemove

I'm using the below code to change my cursor image depending on the cursors position. I've notice that if the cursor travels across a label or textbox or something, the cursor will not change until it enters over part of my tablelayout, which could change mid page.

```
    Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.MouseMove
    If e.Location.X > Me.Width - 7 And e.Location.Y > 12 And e.Location.Y < Me.Height - 12 Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE
    ElseIf e.Location.X < 6 And e.Location.Y > 12 And e.Location.Y < Me.Height - 12 Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE
    ElseIf e.Location.Y > Me.Width - 12 And e.Location.X > 12 And e.Location.X < Me.Width - 12 Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS
    ElseIf e.Location.Y < 6 And e.Location.X > 12 And e.Location.X < Me.Width - 12 Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS
    Else
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub
```

What I wondering, is there a different mousemove event that will only concentrate on the cursor position and not what its travelling over. I've tried form mousemove, but that didn't work.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: This is entirely normal, those other controls get the MouseMove event instead.  You'd have to set the Capture property to True to avoid this from happening.  Not something that is actually useful, this is not a problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the `MouseMove` event for the parent `TableLayoutPanel` and all its children with a single method and simply translate the location as required.

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.MouseMove
    Dim ctrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Dim location = TableLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(ctrl.PointToScreen(e.Location))

    'location is now a Point relative the the top-left corner of TableLayoutPanel1.
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub HandleMouseMoveForTableChildren()
    For Each child As Control In TableLayoutPanel1.Controls
        RemoveHandler child.MouseMove, AddressOf TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove
        AddHandler child.MouseMove, AddressOf TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove
    Next
End Sub
```

Just call that secoind method any time a child control is added to the table and the first method will then work as you want.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney, one more question if I can. It seems the other controls now inherit the tablelayout event. For example if the cursor changes at 5px from the top of the tablelayout, the cursor will also change at 5px from the top of ever other control, well at least thats whats happening at the momemt. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Hmmm, I might be able to use an if statement to recognize the control change. Not sure how to do that at this point, but I should be able to figure it out if it's possible.

Comment: Sorry, ignore me, it works perfectly. I forgot to amend my code to read location.x instead e.location.x.